# write()-ing an encoded string in Python 3.x

Tags: unicode, python-3.x

I've got a unicode string (s) which I want to write into a file.

In Python 2 I could write:

```
open('filename', 'w').write(s.encode('utf-8'))
```

But this fails for Python 3. Apparently, s.encode() returns something of type 'bytes', which the write() function does not accept:

```
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Does anyone know how to port the above code to Python 3?

Edit:

Thanks to all of you who proposed using binary mode! Unfortunately, this causes a problem with the \n characters. Is there any way to achieve the same result I had with Python 2 (namely to encode non-ANSI characters in UTF-8 while keeping the OS-specific rendition of \n)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file in binary mode, that's the least invasive way in terms of changes.

On the other hand, you could set the output file encoding with open() and avoid explicit string encoding altogether.

You might want to read the manual of the [open()](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#open) function.

Comment: I chose to accept this answer, because it helped me - the Python novice - to understand that there are two valid options: working with a **text** file, in which case I need to set the `encoding` when `open()`-ing the file, or with a **binary** file, which would be very similar to what I had before (but cause some difficulty with handling newlines, but I guess with a bit of extra effort I could treat them too). By now I have come to know and appreciate the Python 3.x way of distinguishing between **text** (`str`) and (binary) **data** (`bytes`).

Answer (score 16):

You do *not* want to muck around with manually encoding each and every piece of data like that! Simply pass the encoding as an argument to `open`, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2

slist = [
    "Ca\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE}on City",
    "na\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH DIAERESIS}vet\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE}",
    "fa\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA}ade",
    "\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA}-globulin"
]

with open("/tmp/sample.utf8", mode="w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    for s in slist:
        print(s, file=f)
```

Now if you the file you made, you’ll see that it says:

```
$ cat /tmp/sample.utf8
Cañon City
naïveté
façade
β-globulin
```

And you can see that those are the right code points this way:

```
$ uniquote -x /tmp/sample.utf 
Ca\x{F1}on City
na\x{EF}vet\x{E9}
fa\x{E7}ade
\x{3B2}-globulin
```

See how much easier that is?  Let the stream object handle any low-level encoding or decoding for you.

**Summary:** Don't call `encode` or `decode` yourself when all you are doing is using them to process a homogeneous stream that's all of it in the same encoding.  That's way too much bother for zero gain. Use the `encoding` argument just once and for all.

Comment: No reason not to use `with` in 3.2. Also, `f.close()`, not `f.close`.

Comment: @agf Ug, you’re right. How do I make Python warn me about such silly mistakes?  In Perl I would have gotten a "Useless use of constant in void context" or some such.

Comment: @Lennart: Thanks, but why is it better? Scoping control on `f`?

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, and f gets closed even if you raise an error, etc. See http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm and http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Comment: @Lennart That sounds like it means that the destructor for that class does not do a close when the file object gets garbage collected. Otherwise the exception won't make a difference. Isn't that a bug? Perl handles all have destructors that automatically close them for you, so it doesn't matter if you raise an exception. This is really important for resource management. It's too important to be left up to the programmer to forget to do right.

Comment: You don't know when it gets garbage collected. You are right it is important for resource management. That's why you should use `with`.

Comment: @Lennart: Why in the world don’t I know when it gets garbage collected?  Isn’t it when it is no longer reachable? Please don’t tell me this is like Java! I thought Python had deterministic resource management, not the pussyfooting that Java has. Everything I’ve read says the Python is by default deterministic via reference counting. I despise non-determinism in resource management: it’s unmanageable.

Comment: Yes, it uses reference counting. Again it's **WHEN**. You don't control when GC is called (unless you do it explicitly, which deafeats the purpose).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3361/discussion-between-lennart-regebro-and-tchrist)

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in binary mode

```
open('filename', 'wb').write(s.encode('utf-8'))
```