# Python won't write '♥' character to text document

Tags: python-3.x, file, utf-8

I've got a bit of an annoying issue, I'm trying to write a series of json data to a text document, however, python raises a UnicodeEncodeError whenever it encounters these kinds of characters.

As per the big update with python 3, these characters print to the console just fine, its the issue when we go

```
with open("filename.txt", "a") as file
file.write("I ♥ ice cream")
file.close()
```

As I'm still a newbie to python, I haven't the slightest clue how to solve this, any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write()-ing an encoded string in Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372974/write-ing-an-encoded-string-in-python-3-x)

Comment: You don't need `file.close()` when you're using a `with open(...)` block, but you do need a colon and sensible indentation.

Comment: The syntax corrected version of your code works just fine on Python 3.5. http://imgur.com/a/GxQ0s

Comment: @ayhan Ah, I'm using python 3.6.1, since this seems to be an issue with regards to the version of python, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to solve this one!

First off I'd like to thank @JJJ, for hinting me down the right track, however my only criticism is that the presented solution wasn't very straight forward, and for someone with no knowledge of the significance of bytes and strings this may present quite the challenge.

Basically the problem was to do with the default method of encoding that my computer uses (the OS being the standard win 10), being cp1252.

When going into python and having the program run a simple bit of code to test this, it more clearly illustrates the issue and thus we can find a more viable solution.

```
text = "I ♥ IceCream"
text = text.encode("cp1252")
open('People Jobs.txt','a').write(text)
```

Running this in IDLE, we get this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2665' in position 2: character maps to <undefined>
```

Ah! Now we can see our issue! The codec can't encode the character! Knowing this we can encode the string using utf-8 before writing it to the file like so:

```
text = "I ♥ IceCream"
text = text.encode("utf-8")
open('People Jobs.txt','a').write(text)
```

Running this, we finally get:

```
b'I \xe2\x99\xa5 IceCream'
```

Which can be written to the file no worries. We can turn this back into the original message using the decode method, however for my purposes, we don't need to do that.

Once again, I'd like to extend my thanks to those who commented on my post, your extensive knowledge of the python language is quite the asset and I greatly appreciate it.

Hopefully my negligence to see these simple programming principles will benefit others when they come to laugh at this post

But hey that's why I have the name!

So until next time,

- Mr Incompetent

P.S @Pratik K Thank you for the reminder of how to write this one in a more compact manner, I appreciate it :) (been doing C++ for a while so I've forgotten about python)

Comment: The important part here is the fact, that it is on Windows, which uses `cp1252` per default. The responses, telling, it works for them, probably use `utf-8` encoding per default. It may also work, if you change the encoding of your python file to `utf-8`, so that any string is unicode already (hope I got this right; [python docs for this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out, seems to work just fine. Just a side note, instead of using `with ...`, you can just as well write this out as: `open(filename, 'a' ).write(string)`. This will open up the file, write/ append to it, and close it, all within one line.
Just to be clear, the syntax for your solution would be:

```
with open("filename.txt", 'a') as file:
    file.write("I ♥ ice cream")
```

Comment: Still Isn't working for me, are you using IDLE? and what version of python?

Comment: @Mr_incompetent I tried it out on both Python 3.5.2 and Python 3.6.0, it works fine on both. Looks, like you've solved it though, glad I could be of some help.

Comment: Thank you kind sir you have been an asset tonight, I really appreciate your help :)